# onchange function isn't triggering on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a chain of dropdowns that update depending on the prior selection, i.e.

```
 <p>Department:</p>
  
  <select id="acr" onchange="fn()">
    <option value=""></option>
    {% for x in acr%}
    <option value="{{x}}">{{ x }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>

  <p>Semester:</p>

  <select id="sem" onchange="fn()">
    <option value=""></option>
    {% for p in sem%}
    <option value="{{p}}">{{ p }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>

  <p>Course:</p>

  <select id = 'cla' name="classes">
    <option value=""></option>
    {% for y in results %}
    <option value="{{y}}">{{ y[1] }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

and everything works perfectly on desktop. However, for some reason the onchange function doesn't seem to be triggered when using a mobile browser; I've tested on Safari and Google Chrome. Here is some of the relevant JS:

```
const fn = () => {
      const major = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0]
      const semester = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[1]
      const classes = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[2]
  
      const opts = Array.from(classes.getElementsByTagName('option'))
  
      console.log(opts[1].value)
      opts.forEach(function (k) {
        if (!k.value) {
          return
        }
```

I've also tried adding onkeyup/down functions but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I tried your code on mobile by codepen and it's working. You have used ES6 syntax, Some older mobile browser doesn't support them, I haven't look at the functionality of your fn(), just checked if it's executing or not. Try this codepen : https://codepen.io/mdrezwanferdous/pen/JjGLYmw

For Mobile try full screen:  https://codepen.io/mdrezwanferdous/full/JjGLYmw

Comment: @Niloy could the issue be somewhere in the hosting of the application on heroku ?

Answer (score -1):

Is this happening only on iOS? If yes, try adding `cursor:pointer` to the `body` tag. Make sure the style is inline `<body style="cursor:pointer;">`